# How to tell if Youtube Parental Controls are on and working in iOS?

Tags: ipad, youtube

I am using Youtube parental controls for my 9-year-old's iPad.  The standard way to do this is to create a Google account for your child, which I have, and then choose one of two options:

(1) Use the Youtube Kids app.

(2) Use the standard Youtube app and choose a content option (9+, 13+, etc).

I'm exploring option (2).  (When I originally got the iPad, I set it up to be restricted following some kind of tutorial that I no longer remember.  I think the options above are more recent, unless the tutorial was just not complete.)

So I go into my Youtube account and select the parental controls from (on iPhone):

[My Icon in Youtube] -> Settings -> Parent Settings -> [My Child's Account]

Then on the "Youtube and Youtube Music Settings" you can Edit and select what you want, here I've selected "Explore" (9+).

Ok, so now I go on my child's iPad, which is signed into Youtube using *my child's* account.  First, I notice that there is no "Parent Settings" in her account - great, I don't want her changing my Parent settings.

**However, there appears to be *no indication* as to whether her Youtube experience recognizes that she is be limited using the "Explore" (9+) option.  How do I tell whether it's working???**

Worse: if I go to her Settings -> General, there is a "Restricted Mode" setting which I can toggle ON/Off signed on as *her account*.  This mode is described as "This helps hide potentially mature videos.  This setting only applies to this app on this device."  What???

How is there a setting for my child's account that can toggle mature video on and off???

This entire thing is not clear at all.  What is Google doing?  Can anyone give some insight?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there anything on Googles help pages for YT on this? Or can you search for some YT videos with mature content (stuff with EXPLICIT in the name may qualify) with your account and then check? Basically this more about YT than about Apple products.

Comment: Have you tried accessing or playing the type of videos you are concerned about? If you can’t play them good, if you can’t find them, even better…

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah I was gonna say just look up the stuff you don't want them seeing

Comment: Lol, it's the internet.  It's more: what am I NOT concerned about?  But thanks, I'll play around a bit.